# What does `sample_weight` do to the way a `DecisionTreeClassifier` works in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

I've read from the [relevant documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tips-on-practical-use) that :

> Class balancing can be done by sampling an equal number of samples from each class, or preferably by normalizing the sum of the sample weights (`sample_weight`) for each class to the same value.

But, it is still unclear to me how this works.  If I set `sample_weight` with an array of only two possible values, `1`'s and `2`'s, does this mean that the samples with `2`'s will get sampled twice as often as the samples with `1`'s when doing the bagging?  I cannot think of a practical example for this.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Some quick preliminaries:

Let's say we have a classification problem with K classes. In a region of feature space represented by the node of a decision tree, recall that the "impurity" of the region is measured by quantifying the inhomogeneity, using the probability of the class in that region. Normally, we estimate:

```
Pr(Class=k) = #(examples of class k in region) / #(total examples in region)
```

The impurity measure takes as input, the array of class probabilities:

```
[Pr(Class=1), Pr(Class=2), ..., Pr(Class=K)]
```

and spits out a number, which tells you how "impure" or how inhomogeneous-by-class the region of feature space is. For example, the gini measure for a two class problem is `2*p*(1-p)`, where `p = Pr(Class=1)` and `1-p=Pr(Class=2)`.

---

Now, basically the short answer to your question is:

**`sample_weight` augments the probability estimates in the probability array** ... which augments the impurity measure ... which augments how nodes are split ... which augments how the tree is built ... which augments how feature space is diced up for classification.

I believe this is best illustrated through example.

---

First consider the following 2-class problem where the inputs are 1 dimensional:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier as DTC

X = [[0],[1],[2]] # 3 simple training examples
Y = [ 1,  2,  1 ] # class labels

dtc = DTC(max_depth=1)
```

So, we'll look trees with just a root node and two children. Note that the default impurity measure the gini measure.

---

## Case 1: no `sample_weight`

```
dtc.fit(X,Y)
print dtc.tree_.threshold
# [0.5, -2, -2]
print dtc.tree_.impurity
# [0.44444444, 0, 0.5]
```

The first value in the `threshold` array tells us that the 1st training example is sent to the left child node, and the 2nd and 3rd training examples are sent to the right child node. The last two values in `threshold` are placeholders and are to be ignored. The `impurity` array tells us the computed impurity values in the parent, left, and right nodes respectively.

In the parent node, `p = Pr(Class=1) = 2. / 3.`, so that `gini = 2*(2.0/3.0)*(1.0/3.0) = 0.444....`. You can confirm the child node impurities as well.

---

## Case 2: with `sample_weight`

Now, let's try:

```
dtc.fit(X,Y,sample_weight=[1,2,3])
print dtc.tree_.threshold
# [1.5, -2, -2]
print dtc.tree_.impurity
# [0.44444444, 0.44444444, 0.]
```

You can see the feature threshold is different. `sample_weight` also affects the impurity measure in each node. Specifically, in the probability estimates, the first training example is counted the same, the second is counted double, and the third is counted triple, due to the sample weights we've provided.

The impurity in the parent node region is the same. This is just a coincidence. We can compute it directly:

```
p = Pr(Class=1) = (1+3) / (1+2+3) = 2.0/3.0
```

The gini measure of `4/9` follows.

Now, you can see from the chosen threshold that the first and second training examples are sent to the left child node, while the third is sent to the right. We see that impurity is calculated to be `4/9` also in the left child node because:

```
p = Pr(Class=1) = 1 / (1+2) = 1/3.
```

The impurity of zero in the right child is due to only one training example lying in that region.

You can extend this with non-integer sample-wights similarly. I recommend trying something like `sample_weight = [1,2,2.5]`, and confirming the computed impurities.

Comment: For the `gini measure`, shouldn't it be `2/3 * (1 - 2/3) = 2/9`?  Okay so I see that it affects the impurity measure, but how would this be different from just sampling a certain sample more frequently or less frequently based on relative `sample weights`?  Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: The gini measure is `2*p*(1-p)` for binary classification, which is why the result is 4/9. You're correct in your interpretation. However, "sampling" suggests randomness, which there is not (just to be clear). When `sample_weights` are integers, it's like replicating the `ith` training example `samples_weights[i]` times in the impurity measure. Of course, `sample_weights` do not have to be integers, but the idea is the same.

Comment: I wonder if similar procedures are performed when `criterion = 'entropy'`

Comment: IIRC @Chris the impurity measure is abstracted away to a configurable callable and that callable used in the relevant bits, so it should work the same, independent of any particular choice of criterion. Although, it's been quite a while since I dived into the source to pick it apart. The code is pretty is to follow, though, so you could def give it reading to see.

Comment: @MattHancock @Brick This is a good answer but it would be very helpful to explain how an optimal sample weight for a classifier is computed, for example by [`sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_sample_weight`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_sample_weight.html).

Comment: But does it affect prediction calculations? E.g. if we have 10 of class 0 and 5 of class 1 in a leaf, but the weights are [0.1, 100], will the prediction be class 0 or 1?

Comment: I dug through the source code but didn't come up with a conclusive answer. But trying a demo problem seemed to suggest the weights do not affect the predictions and only affect the Gini or entropy criteria.