# How precisely does the class_weight parameter work in sci-kit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of the class_weight parameter in sci-kit learn. How exactly does the class_weight penalize errors for certain classes? Is it weighting errors in the loss function?

Comment: This depends on a particular model, not scikit-learn.

Comment: As a particular example for trees, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389624/what-does-sample-weight-do-to-the-way-a-decisiontreeclassifier-works-in-skle/34477381#34477381).

Comment: Nice example. Thanks