# Figuring out why scikit-learn DecisionTreeClassifier decided to exclude a feature from the resulting decision tree?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using `scikit-learn`'s `DecisionTreeClassifier` to construct a decision tree for a particular feature-set. To my surprise, one feature which was thought to be significant - was excluded.

Is there a way to take a peek under the hood, and figure out why the algorithm chose to exclude that feature?

Or really, get more information / analytics about any part of the decision-tree construction process?

Comment: How are you saying that it has been excluded? Are you looking at the underlying `tree_`? Maybe check the `feature_importance_` of the fitted tree.

Comment: @VivekKumar: I used `export_graphviz()` and the feature isn't in the rendered tree.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your problem with a feature ignoring, its hard to tell why, but I can suggest to "play" with the weights of the `sample_weight` flag to change the weight each sample get, and therefore give more weight to the mentioned feature, which you can read an excellent explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34477381/3580365).

Also, for debugging, there is a way to save an image of the trained tree, as demonstrated in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html):

The `export_graphviz` exporter supports a variety of aesthetic options, including coloring nodes by their class (or value for regression) and using explicit variable and class names if desired. `IPython` notebooks can also render these plots inline using the `Image()` function:

```
from IPython.display import Image
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None,  # clf: the trained classifier
                         feature_names=iris.feature_names,  
                         class_names=iris.target_names,  
                         filled=True, rounded=True,  
                         special_characters=True)  
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, sample_weight is used to assign more weight to a whole sample (not a feature).