# `sample_weight` in sklearn LogisticRegression: How It Works?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, liblinear

`fit` method of `LogisticRegression` has a optional `sample_weight` parameter. I follow the python code and find it just does some trivial things and dispatches to underlying solvers (e.g. liblinear). How `sample_weight` works? does it work thought oversampling or some other method?

### update

as @Alexander McFarlane said, it isn't immediately obvious that the sample weight in the decision tree is the same as the logistic regression unless you look at the source.

Comment: It's hard to answer this in detail but I can only assume sample weight might be an initial bias vector. This can be used to help center the input data on the sigmoid

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit)?

Comment: And maybe searched the stackoverflow for some closely related questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389624/what-does-sample-weight-do-to-the-way-a-decisiontreeclassifier-works-in-skle

Comment: @VivekKumar I would argue that it isn't immediately obvious that the sample weight in the decision tree is the same as the logistic regression unless you look at the source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \`sample\_weight\` do to the way a \`DecisionTreeClassifier\` works in sklearn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389624/what-does-sample-weight-do-to-the-way-a-decisiontreeclassifier-works-in-skle)

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Yes, I agree. But the underlying concept is almost same, of augmenting the probabilities (giving more attention to those samples than others which have higher weights).

Comment: @VivekKumar either way - you were very helpful in finding that original answer so I deleted mine

Comment: @VivekKumar I've read the documentation carefully before ask. only usage is documented, and what I'm curious about is how it works (mechanism), not how to use it